# React Native & Redux should I have a Store per Scene/Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using `react-native-router-flux` to manage navigation in my app. I wanted to know if I should create a store for each scene or should I only create one (**and how**?)

Right now it looks like this:

**App.js**

```
 <Router>
    <Scene key="root">
      <Scene key="mainScene" component={MainScene} title="MainScene" initial={true} />
      <Scene key="secondScene" component={SecondScene} title="SecondScene" />
    </Scene>
 </Router>
```

**MainScene.js**

```
 <Provider store={store}>
     <MainConnectedComponent/>
 </Provider>
```

**SecondScene.js**

```
 <Provider store={store}>
     <SecondConnectedComponent/>
 </Provider>
```

I read somewhere that redux likes only one store, but I don't know how to make that possible with this kind of navigation that separates the app to different parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use only one store, but you separate the reducers.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const mainSceneReducer = (state, action) => {
    ...
};

const secondSceneReducer = (state, action) => {
    ...
};

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        mainSceneReducer,
        secondSceneReducer
    });
);
```

**Update:** Now about the router, you would put your Provider around your main Router, and remove it from mainScene.js and secondScene.js:

```
<Provider store={store}>
 <Router>
    <Scene key="root">
      <Scene key="mainScene" component={MainScene} title="MainScene" initial={true} />
      <Scene key="secondScene" component={SecondScene} title="SecondScene" />
    </Scene>
 </Router>
</Provider>
```

Related SO question: [redux-multiple-stores-why-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619775/redux-multiple-stores-why-not)

Comment: Can you please show me how this works with the navigation? should I put the provider there?