# Can I have my apps share single redux store?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a complex analytics html page, I have converted most of the elements into react components, most of my elements are organized into two sections top / bottom.

My setup is working, yet, I'm wondering if this is legal / correct way of setting things up?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import TopSection from './components/app';
import BottomSection from './components/app_content';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

// Top Section 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <TopSection />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.top-section'));

// Bottom Section 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BottomSection />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.bottom-section'));
```

Comment: Do you mean you'd like them to use a single store? Since here you're creating two stores that just share the reducers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple store if it is really needed. But it is strongly recommoneded to **NOT** go with multiple store setups. Single store is always best choice because,

- it's reliable
- it's fast
- debugging is easy

Here are the links, why multiple store setup is not recommended.

[redux.js.org](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html#store-setup-multiple-stores)

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619775/redux-multiple-stores-why-not)