# can we have multiple stores in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have requirement where i need to open a popup from main react application and this popup will have to have a seperate redux store from parent(its one more big application  as good as parent application). Can we communicate between two?

Idea is to have this popup application as a node module and use in different pages  as reusable component.  So now i have coupe of questions

1. can we have 2 redux stores created and make them communicate each
   other
2. i saw something about maintaining sub apps, give here
   https://gist.github.com/gaearon/eeee2f619620ab7b55673a4ee2bf8400 .
   Can we maintain communication between the main app and sub app
   stores?
3. How to maintain the router in a popup application, As the
   history back doesnt work in popup window. Any ideas here?

Would appreciate if you can share any live example.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, you can simply organize that one store to contain two big objects - one for the app and one for the sub, and then maintain the option to communicate whilst having a separate state object.

Comment: Question is already answered here >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556221/8625811

Answer (score 1):

The original Flux pattern describes having multiple “stores” in an app, each one holding a different area of domain data. This can introduce issues such as needing to have one store “waitFor” another store to update. This is not necessary in Redux because the separation between data domains is already achieved by splitting a single reducer into smaller reducers. Hope i could help
[read more in the link](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can. Check [this](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#multiple-stores) doc.

Wrap main component with Providers:

```js
const ContextA = React.createContext();
const ContextB = React.createContext();

const storeA = createStore(reducerA);
const storeB = createStore(reducerB);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={storeA} context={ContextA} />
      <Provider store={storeB} context={ContextB}>
        <RootModule />
      </Provider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Example with connect:

```js
connect(mapStateA, null, null, { context: ContextA })(MyComponentA)

// You may also pass the alternate context instance directly to the connected component instead
<ConnectedMyComponentA context={ContextA} />

// it is possible to chain connect()
// in this case MyComponent will receive merged props from both stores
compose(
  connect(mapStateA, null, null, { context: ContextA }),
  connect(mapStateB, null, null, { context: ContextB })
)(MyComponent);
```

Example with hooks:

```js
// Create custom useSelector hook with context and use instead of importing from react-redux

export const useSelectorA = createSelectorHook(ContextA)
export const useSelectorB = createSelectorHook(ContextB)

...

function Component() {
  const aData = useSelectorA(aSelector)
  const bData = useSelectorB(bSelector)

  return ...
}
```

Also remember, there is no reason to create custom `useStore` and `useDispatch` at all, just import needed `store` directly, and you can also export its dispatch and later import directly.

But keep in mind that there are not much reasons to create multiple stores. Example - for performance optimization. Or as in your case - separation by application domain.