# react naive connect to two redux in the same page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

this is how i connect to RegisterUser redux
 i want to connect to another redux

RegisterUser to send data to api 
in the second redux i want to fetch task from api but when i try to connect another redux it is give me this error

invalid value of type object for mapstatetoprops argument when connecting component

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
   errorid: state.RegisterR.errorid,
    loading: state.RegisterR.loading,
    registersucsess:state.RegisterR.registersucsess
}}


 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { RegisterUser })(Register);






what i try to do something like this const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    errorid: state.RegisterR.errorid,
    loading: state.RegisterR.loading,
    registersucsess:state.RegisterR.registersucsess,


    data: state.taskList.data}}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchTasks},{ RegisterUser })(Register);
```

Comment: Are you combining your reducers? Can you show your store where you set up your reducers?

Comment: when you mean `another redux` do you mean `two different stores`

Comment: yes it is two different stores

Comment: This should help you https://medium.com/@azizhk/create-multiple-redux-stores-b77b7359375f . But highly recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619775/redux-multiple-stores-why-not

Comment: Hopefully an working example i think for your use-case https://codesandbox.io/s/92pm9n2kl4

Answer (score 0):

thank you all i have one store

and i combining my reducer import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

what i want to use two actions in same screen

i manage to do that like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    errorid: state.RegisterR.errorid,
    loading: state.RegisterR.loading,
    registersucsess:state.RegisterR.registersucsess,

    data: state.taskList.data // this is for fetchTasks }}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { RegisterUser ,fetchTasks})(Register);
```